# Not able to retrieve cookie data from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, cookies, multidimensional-array

I'm new to cookies here is how i'm setting and retrieving data

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['cart'])){
$_COOKIE['cart'] = array();
}

setcookie("cart[$stk_id]['name']", $name, time()+24*60*60, "/");
setcookie("cart[$stk_id]['quantity']", $qty, time()+24*60*60, "/");
setcookie("cart[$stk_id]['vendor']", $vendor, time()+24*60*60, "/");

foreach ($_COOKIE['cart'] as $stk_id => $product){
    $qty = $product['quantity'];
    $pro_name = $product['name'];
}
```

but i'm getting error Notice: Undefined index: quantity and name. 
what is the problem?

Comment: looks more like a job for sessions than cookies

Comment: I'm comfortable to sessios but not sure about cookies

Answer (score 0):

Cookies array store is commonly used by once variable ,you are set cookies name in array,but create array first and after set cookie name is more convenient.Here you can set by `json_encode` and `json_decode`

```
$data = array($stk_id => 
              array(
                   "name" => $name,
                   "quantity" => $qty,
                   "vendor" => $vendor
                   )
             );
setcookie("cart", json_encode($data), time()+24*60*60, "/");   
$cookie = json_decode($_COOKIE['cart'],true);//for array output

foreach ($cookie as $stk_id => $product){
            $qty = $product['quantity'];
            $pro_name = $product['name'];
}
```